# sync android with google biz apps calender

Tags: android

A buddy of mine got a new android phone (i use iphone so im a little new to it) but he can sync his gmail calender but not his google biz apps calender that we use for works.

is there any trick to getting it to sync with his phone so he can make edits and have them reflected in his "work" calender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Android v2.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0-highlights.html) you can log into multiple Google accounts on your Android phone. So, if your friend's phone uses Android 2.0+ he can simply add a new account (his Google Apps one) to the calendar application (assuming he currently uses his personal account for the phone).

I myself have my personal and Google Apps calendars synced to my phone and everything works perfectly (I have a HTC Magic running CyanogenMod 6.0/Android 2.2).

Comment: Do you have the instructions on how to do so. I don't have a unit in front of me to help walk the user through with.

Comment: To add additional account on your phone: Settings -> Accounts & sync -> Add account. After you add your secondary account, in the Accounts & sync menu click on the newly added account and select the "Sync Calendar" option. Next you should open the Calendar application, press the "Menu" button to open the contextual menu, choose More -> Calendars and you should see a list of all your calendars, grouped by the account they belong to. On this screen you can choose which calendars are visible and sync-ed. Hope this helps.